# Jbehave not able to find the story

Tags: java, testng, bdd, jbehave

When i am trying to run the Java class having @Test annotation as a part part of TestNG for JBehave it is giving org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound exception.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6eL.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6eL.jpg
Code:
public class Runner extends ConfigurableEmbedder {

```
public Embedder embedder;
@Test
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    embedder = configuredEmbedder();
    embedder.configuration();
    System.out.println("I am runner");
    [Image attached for reference][1]
    String storypath= "GoogleSearch.story";
    embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Collections.singletonList(storypath));
    
}
```

Comment: This is my first Question on Stackoverflow, please ignore the mistakes. TIA

Comment: Mistakes can't be ignored; they must be corrected so that a question is answerable. See [ask] and check the [help] for guidelines.